# sproutcore backend

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

Does sproutcore need backend? is it reliable as Java for webapps? or does it use only for client-side programming? what about apple's projects as iworks.com and mobileme.com? do they programmed by sproutcore and javascript only or use also something else for backend as Java (webobjects)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are trying to do.  You can develop client side functionality with Sproutcore without a backend using their Fixture abstraction. However, usually RIAs by their nature are hooked up to a back-end somehow.  I imagine with HTML5 and whatnot there will be some client-side only applications.  Sproutcore is ideal for these, as are other JS frameworkds.

Your question about "reliable as java for webapps" doesn't make sense.  Sproutcore is reliable in that the framework works, and is open source, so if you find a bug you can fix/patch it.  Furthermore, it promotes TDD by shipping with unit test examples.

To be clear, Sproutcore is NOT a server side technology. It only works on the client (i.e. browser or equivalent).

Comment: Just to clarify, SC does not require a backend, but if you want data to be accessible between multiple computers it will be necessary.